# I am getting System check error, how can I solve It?

Tags: django-models

when I am using two foreignkeys in a mdels it through an error "SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:app1.GroupOfCompany.c_company: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'CompanyDetails.groupofcompany_set' for 'app1.GroupOfCompany.c_company' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app1.GroupOfCompany.p_company_id'."

I try to Change the names but it is showing same error. How can I solve this error?